# Checking Open Ports PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp, port

I am having issues sending mail using SMTP from a shared web server (Apache), although it works on my localhost (XAMPP) environment.

I've been advised (by other people that had similar issues) to check if the remote web server has the port 587 opened and available.

The code I am using is below;

```
    $fp = fsockopen("smtp.office365.com", 587, $errno, $errstr, 5); 
    if (!$fp)
        echo "smtp.office365.com 587  -  $errstr   ($errno)<br>\n";
    else
        echo "smtp.office365.com 587 -  ok<br>\n";
```

When I run this **locally** I see the following message;

> smtp.office365.com 587 - ok

When I run this on the **remote** server I see;

> smtp.office365.com 587 - Connection timed out (110)

Along with the PHP error;

> Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to smtp.office365.com:587
>   (Connection timed out)

So. it looks like I *can* connect via my localhost, but *can't* via the remote host.

My question is, what does this mean exactly? And is there anything I can suggest to my web host that they need to configure or check? They are convinved there is an error in my code, however I feel that the issue is at their end - not sure how I can convince them of this :/

Thanks

Comment: You could ask for the firewall configuration, it could be they've blocked port 587.

Comment: Thanks @FMashiro I'll ask them for this, not sure if they will provide it though. Is there any way I can check it's blocked from my end?